# How to close all elements that are opened with jquery? (Behavior similar to the accordion menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuFuncionalidades">
        <li>
            <div class="menuFuncionalidades_categoria">
                <a href="/sttenterprise/">Index</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="menuFuncionalidades_categoria">
                <a href="#">Cadastros</a></div>
            <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links">
                <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_descricao">
                    <span class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_descricao_titulo">Descrição</span>
                    <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_descricao_texto">
                        Lorem Ipsum...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_links">
                    <ul><b>Acesso Usuario</b>
                        <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incluir</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Alterar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consultar</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul><b>Produto</b>
                        <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incluir</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul><b>Perfil</b>
                        <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incluir</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="menuFuncionalidades_categoria">
                <a href="#">Coletores</a></div>
            <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links">
                <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_descricao">
                    <span class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_descricao_titulo">Descrição</span>
                    <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_descricao_texto">
                        Lorem Ipsum...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menuFuncionalidades_content_links_links">
                    <ul>
                        <b>Coletor 1</b>
                        <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incluir</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <b>Coletor 2</b>
                        <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incluir</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <b>Coletor 3</b>
                        <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incluir</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My objective is when i click in a `menuFuncionalidades_categoria` i close all `menuFuncionalidades_content_links` that is opened, and opened the right one that is in the same level of the `menuFuncionalidades_categoria` that i click. So, i try this, but i have no success:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menuFuncionalidades > li > .menuFuncionalidades_categoria').click(function () {
        $("#menu").children().find('.menuFuncionalidades_content_links').each(function () {
            // I need a code here to close only the tags that are opened but is not the current
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

        $(this).parent().find('.menuFuncionalidades_content_links').slideToggle('normal').css('width', $('#menu').css('width'));
    });
});
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

OBS: The behavior that i want, is similar with accordion menu.

DEMO here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ry9dz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @karim79 says, you can't check "display" that way - it's a css attribute, not an html attribute.

On the other hand, if you want to close all other entries, then just do that - no need to check if they are visible first! I also suggest you use a more efficient event handler for all your items, instead of binding it to all of them. Using jQuery 1.7, something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#menuFuncionalidades").on("click", ".menuFuncionalidades_categoria", function(event) {
    var selectedMenu = $(event.target).parents("li").find(".menuFuncionalidades_content_links")
      , visible = selectedMenu.is(":visible");

    // Hide all others
    $("#menuFuncionalidades .menuFuncionalidades_content_links").hide();
    // Show this one unless it was already visible
    if(!visible) {
      selectedMenu
        .slideToggle('normal')
        .css('width', $('#menu').css('width'));
    }
    // Prevent the default action
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, if i do this, i ll close everyone incluinding the current that is opened. So, if i click on one is already opened, it 'll close and open again, but i want to close if is already opened.

Comment: The behavior that i want, is similar with accordion menu.  (i edited the question in the js code)

Comment: I test the code now, is almost! The behavior that is missing, is close the current if i click on it.

Comment: There you have it. You might want to do some extra check rather than just "is(':visible')" if you want to catch it in the middle of the animation as well - it seems to not be considered visible if it's in the middle of the animation.

Comment: Let me understand one thing... why there is a comma after the find method?

Comment: No need to use `slideToggle()` if the element always is visible.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: I'm declaring two variables. These are all equal: https://gist.github.com/1826712

It's just a personal preference.

Comment: @Stefan: True we could just do slideDown() (it's always _not_ visible).

Answer (score 1):

You can hide multiple elements without iterating though all of them to see which ones aren't hidden.

Replace;

```
$("#menu").children().find('.menuFuncionalidades_content_links').each(function () {
  if ($(this).attr('display') == 'block') {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

with;

```
$("#menu").find('.menuFuncionalidades_content_links').hide();
```

`$(this).attr('display')` is invalid as there are no "display" attribute and instead of using `.css('display') == 'block'` you could simply use the psuedo selector `:visible`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the display *css* property:

```
if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

or:

```
if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: and even more important, prevent the default action on the click :P

Comment: I'm a newbie with jquery, so, what is this (the objective with the prevent default action on the click)?

Comment: @meo - why, the element with the handler attached to it is a div. What default action?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni - both do the same thing, in different ways.

Comment: @karim79 sorry forget it :P i clicked the first navigation link

Comment: The behavior that i want, is similar with accordion menu. (i edited the question in the js code)